# remove div even if single ul li empty inside the div

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have following code....

```
<div id="rem-download-ref" class="download-reference">
    <ul>
        <li><strong>Download »</strong></li>
        <li><asp:Image ID="imgepub" runat="server" align="absmiddle" ImageUrl="/images/icon/epub.png" Visible="false"  width="22" height="22" /><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkePub" runat="server"
                 NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("epub_path").ToString() + Eval("epub_name").ToString() %>'
                 Visible="false">ePUB</asp:HyperLink>
        </li>
        <li><asp:Image ID="imgmobi" runat="server" align="absmiddle" ImageUrl="/images/icon/mobi.png" Visible="false"  width="22" height="22" /><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkMobi" runat="server"
                 NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("mobi_path").ToString() + Eval("mobi_name").ToString() %>'
                 Visible="false">mobi</asp:HyperLink>
         </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

what I need is if any of the **`<li>`** is empty then I want to remove whole div.

how can I do that using javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is not quite clear. But is this what you want?

```
$("#rem-download-ref li").each(function(i, v) {
    if ($(v).text() == "") {
        $("#rem-download-ref").remove();
        break;
    }
});
```

Please do not forget to add `jQuery`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery.com/src/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Comment: This will break on the first empty `li`. It will not evaluate all `li` tags unless they are all not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `<div>` a `<asp:Panel>`. Then on the databound event of your container, set the visibility of the panel to false if `epub_path` and `mobi_path` are null or empty.

It's difficult to give a more detailed answer without more code from you. What kind of control is doing the databinding? `GridView`? `ListView`? `Repeater`? What type of object is the data source?

Answer (score 0):

see if this helps, you may need to wrap it in to a function or place it at least under `rem-download-ref`,

make sure all the elements is inline no spaces

```
<div id="rem-download-ref" class="download-reference"><ul><li id="o1"><strong id="ccc">Download »</strong></li><li id="o2"></li></ul></div>
```

.

```
var dc = document.getElementById("rem-download-ref").firstChild

for (var n = 0; n <dc.childNodes.length; n++) {
    //if (rem-download-ref not null and li not null remove rem-download-ref
   if(dc.parentNode && dc.childNodes[n].firstChild==null){
  dc.parentNode.removeChild(dc);
}
```